# Django: get subset of a model with at least one related model

Tags: python, django, models, django-queryset

```
class Category(models.Model):
    # fields

class Product(models.Model):
     category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
     # fields
```

Assuming that not all the categories have at least a product,

**how i can get all the categories that have at least one product associated**?

Is there a way to do this with Django querysets?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to [`filter`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#filter) on the category.  You want to find the `Category`'s where the product isn't null right?:

```
Category.objects.filter(product_set__isnull=False).distinct()
```

Comment: good one, i didn't think about `isnull`.

anyway the correct form would be `Category.objects.filter(product_set__isnull=False).distinct()` because otherwise we get duplicate categories. Please update the answer